# Capistrano quits deploy with error (error dumping database) when deploying from another repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano

I have created a new repository with the exact same code from another repository on github. The difference is, I copied a branch from previous one to the master of new one.

Capistrano deploy works from previous repository, but it fails from the new repository with this error:

> /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_dump: invalid option -- 'i'
>
> Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
>
> rake aborted!
>
> Error dumping database

I am using rvm and same gemset is being used for both repos.

I have fixed this error on my local environment, but Capistrano still shows it. Most probably it is using gem files from the server. But the question is why doesn't I get error while deploying from old repo.

Other Info

**Rails Version:** 3.2.13

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using postgres 9.5 which does not support --i option. This behaviour of postgres take care in rails 4.2.5 . So either you need to upgrade to rails 4.2.5 or you can downgrade postgres version. I prefer postgres 9.3 personally.

Link [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23030) that suggest upgrade to rails 4.2.5 will did trick.

[Here is link](https://gist.github.com/nruth/a3bc1b75281109b036e4) You can read more.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually Capistrano quits deploying

Comment: Issue with postgres 9.5 also, there is no i option present. So you need to downgrade postgres also. Link https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=11312

Comment: I have updated the question. May be you would have something more to share

Comment: You are using postgres 9.5 which does not support --i option. This behaviour of postgres take care in rails 4.2.5 . So either you need to upgrade to rails 4.2.5 or you can downgrade postgres version. I prefer postgres 9.3 personally.

Comment: my Gemfile.lock says pg (0.17.1)

Comment: System where you deploying having postgres 9.5 installed. You need to completely remove 9.5 and install lower version. I am talking about system dependency not gem.